# How to open an exe file in Tkinter window

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter, virtual-machine

I am trying to open the applications like notepad,photoshop,etc. **inside** the Tkinter window in Python. I tried using **os.sytem()** but it opens independently(not inside Tkinter window).

I had searched a lot about this but didn't got any solution. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want. It is impossible to open an external program inside a Tkinter window.

While it is true that it's possible to embed *some* X11 based apps into an X11 based Tkinter application if the app was designed to be embedded, you will never be able to do this with non-X11 based apps.

Comment: Thanks bryan, but actually I wanted to share software of a user1 with user2 w/o disturbing user1, so I thought of solution of opening application inside tkinter and then use it but as you are saying it's not possible, so is their any other way to approach my problem? I also thought of Virtual Desktop like thing to solve the problem but I think it also doesn't exist till today. And can you give me some X11 links that can be helpful to solve my problem.

Comment: @aki92: if you're trying to open up programs like notepad and photoshop, links to pages related to X11 will be totally useless to you. If you have other questions, the comment section is not the right place to ask them.